# The matter of something

Tags: grammaticality

I just read some articles saying that Google has just announced its latest Android operating system named Android "Nougat".

I wanted to comment about this announcement. I said:

> I thought "Nugget" and "Nougat" were the same and were just the matter of local name

Should "local name" be "local names"?
Or does the phrase "were just the matter of local name" not fit at all?

Comment: "Just a matter of dialect" makes more sense to me. For the record, "nugget" and "nougat" are very different in their meanings.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue is that we would probably say

> just **a** matter of

The second is that we are speaking about *names*, two names, so I think it should be

> just a matter of local names

I don't really see a problem with this.

I feel like some good alternatives are

> just a matter of
>
> 1. localized names
> 2. regional differences
> 3. dialect (as mentioned in the comments)

Comment: How about matters of something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You should [ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question, with all the context and a complete sentence/example.